# Does /boot safe on top of a lvm LV (logical volume)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot, lvm

Title already asked the question. More specifically, I read in some documents that logical volumes are nice in general but not for `/boot` in a linux system. [They](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/LVM-HOWTO/#benefitsoflvmsmall) say that bootloaders don't understand `LVM` volumes, so create a separate partition for `/boot` out of lvm.

I recently installed Ubuntu server (9.10) for my home server, but by default `/boot` is created in the LVM. Everything is fine now, but I am not sure it is safe to use `/boot` in LVM.

Second question is do I really need a physical partition (volume)(pv) for `/boot` or is it equally fine if I put it into a logical volume (lv) on top of a single shared volume group.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

GRUB2 can handle /boot on LVM. I use it on some of my machines. But it's probably safer to have /boot on a partition outside LVM.

Answer (score 0):

Completely wrong and misguiding question. /boot is on a different partition then lvm. Sorry for misguidence. `/swap` is in the logical volume but not `/boot`.